# how to make Material-UI input text field "read only" in angular 12

Tags: html, angular, typescript, material-ui

I want to make a text field read-only so that text field should be non editable ,
I am using Material-UI.
I have tried it making disabled in .ts file of the component

```
 this.firstFormGroup.controls['gauthan_nirmit'].disable();
```

but it does not post data back to server.
The control should be read-only but it must send data back to server when submit is done

Comment: Set readonly in your input. [Set readonly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40863723/9844873)

Answer (score 1):

Just add readonly attribute to the input field in component's .html file

```
<mat-form-field>    
<input matInput readonly number formControlName="gauthan_nirmit" placeholder="" maxlength="5" autocomplete="off" appBlockCopyPaste>
</mat-form-field>
```

It will make control read-only but control data will be sent to data when form is submitted